# Getting text from array of elements protractor

Tags: javascript, arrays, selenium, testing, protractor

this is my first post so please go easy one me. :)

I'am new to protractor therefore I would like to ask for your help.
I've been asked to write a test for the folowing code:

```
<div class="content ps-container ps-active-y expand" ng-class={hide:items.length === 2}" ng-transclude="" csf-product-navigator-content="" csf-scrollbar="" style="">
 <div class="product-wrp prod-active" ng-class="{'prod-active' : active, 'odd' : (odd === true && !active), 'even' : (odd !== true && !active)}" ng-repeat="product in accounts" csf-product-navigator-item="">
  <div class="product-wrp odd" ng-class="{'prod-active' : active, 'odd' : (odd === true && !active), 'even' : (odd !== true && !active)}" ng-repeat="product in accounts" csf-product-navigator-item="">
   <div class="product-item animate-hide" ng-click="onDropdowmItemClick()" ng-transclude="" csf-product-navigator-anim-item="">
    <div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="product in accounts" csf-product-navigator-item="">
     <div class="navigator-view ng-hide" ng-show="active">
      <div class="" ng-hide="active">
       <div class="product-choice ng-scope" ng-if="product.type !== 'SM'">
        <section class="product-name">
         <header class="ng-scope" ng-if="product.name">
          <p class="product-details" ng-show="product.type">
           <span class="ng-binding" ng-bind="product.no">PL84 9101 0003 2001 0006 1883 0004</span>
          </p>
        </section>
        <section class="product-amount">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="product-wrp even" ng-class="{'prod-active' : active, 'odd' : (odd === true && !active), 'even' : (odd !== true && !active)}" ng-repeat="product in accounts" csf-product-navigator-item="">
  <div class="product-wrp even" ng-class="{'prod-active' : active, 'odd' : (odd === true && !active), 'even' : (odd !== true && !active)}" ng-repeat="product in accounts" csf-product-navigator-item="">
  <div class="product-wrp odd" ng-class="{'prod-active' : active, 'odd' : (odd === true && !active), 'even' : (odd !== true && !active)}" ng-repeat="product in accounts" csf-product-navigator-item="">
  <div class="product-wrp even" ng-class="{'prod-active' : active, 'odd' : (odd === true && !active), 'even' : (odd !== true && !active)}" ng-repeat="product in accounts" csf-product-navigator-item="">
```

Goal is to get the number of the products on the dropdown list.

So I figured i should get all elements in the container and then use function to go through them.

This is my code:

features(iOwe):

```
var iOwe = function () {
  this.accNo = element(by.className('content ps-container ps-active-y expand')).all(by.className('product-item animate-hide'))
}
```

Spec(iOwe):

```
it('should display accounts numbers on dropdown list', function () {
  expect(iOwe.accNo.count()).not.toBe(0);
  iOwe.accNo.each(function(elem) {
    elem.element(by.className('product-details')).getText()
    .then
    (function (text){
        console.log(text);
    });
  });
```

The problem is that each time I run tests I get diffrent output in console.
Getting only first 3/4 strings (should be 7) and rest is empty.

Thanks for help

EDIT:
I checked what exactly happens during test by adding 
    `browser.sleep(5000);`
each time console prints string and suprisingly I found out that I have to actually see (in browser) the following account to allow test to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an anwser to my question,it was not a matter of selectors/matchers.

As I found out according to this [Article](http://yizeng.me/2014/04/08/get-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-webdriver/)
in order to .getText() u have to actually see the element in browser otherwise it will return empty string.

I decided to find another way to get the text and I used

```
.getAttribute()
```

to get the string.

Basically i changed :

```
elem.element(by.css('span.ng-binding')).getText()
```

to

```
elem.element(by.css('span.ng-binding')).getAttribute('outerHTML')
```

And it returned string with accnumber.

But...
This is not what I wanted.
I wanted to check if the element is **actually visible** in browser and folowing solution wont work.

Then i found this [Question](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1749),it shows how to scroll down to element in your browser You want to check.

So i edited my code:

```
it('should display accounts numbers on dropdown list', function () {
  expect(iOwe.accNo.count()).not.toBe(0);
  iOwe.accNo.each(function(elem) {
    browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', elem.getWebElement()) //Scroll down to element
    .then
    elem.element(by.className('product-details')).getText()
    .then
    (function (text){
      console.log(text);
    });
});
```

And this is an anwser to my question.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

> Goal is to get the number of the products on the dropdown list.

The most logical way to approach that is to use the [`by.repeater()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater) locator:

```
var products = element.all(by.repeater("product in accounts"));
expect(products.count()).toEqual(7);
```

Or, with a *CSS selector*:

```
var products = $$("p.product-details");
expect(products.count()).toEqual(7);
```

---

If this is a timing issue, you may specifically wait for count of elements matching a locator:

```
function waitForCount(elements, expectedCount) {
    return elements.count().then(actualCount) {
        return actualCount >= expectedCount;
    });
}

browser.wait(waitForCount($$("p.product-details"), 7), 5000);
```

Comment: Ok so i tested both of them and unfortunately first one is too general(it returns account name/ammount).
Second one works like charm but it still returns only 3/4 numbers.

But... I checked what exactly happens during test by adding

    browser.sleep(5000);

each time console prints string and suprisingly i found out that I have to actually see (in browser) the following account to allow test to read it.

Comment: @krzygol alright, does it mean that your issue is now resolved? Thanks.

Comment: Yes I found an anwser and tommorow I will post whole code with the changes and explanation.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this-

```
it('should display accounts numbers on dropdown list', function () {
expect(iOwe.accNo.count()).not.toBe(0);
iOwe.accNo.each(function(elem) {
expect(elem.element(by.css('p.product-details')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
elem.element(by.css('span.ng-binding')).getText()
.then
(function (text){
    console.log(text);
});
});
```

Comment: updated my answer, you could put a extra check whether the product details are displayed and then use the normal chaining elements!